# Ember.js: Update parent template property

Tags: javascript, ember.js, controller, parent

Ey guys I got a simple question about changing a property inside a parent template.
The code that I written is stated below:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('parent' , { path: "/parent" }, function() {
   this.route('child1');
   this.route('child2');
   this.route('child3');
});
```

This router creates the following routes:

- parent
- parent.index
- parent.child1
- parent.child2
- parent.child3

Below are my templates (simplified)

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
{{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="parent">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>

  Common html

  {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="parent/index">
  Parent specific content
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="parent/child1">
  Child 1 specific content
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="parent/child2">
  Child 2 specific content
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="parent/child3">
  Child 3 specific content
</script>
```

And here are my controllers

```
App.ParentController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  title: 'Parent Title'
});

App.ParentIndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  title: 'Parent Index Title'
});

App.Child1Controller = Ember.Controller.extend({
  title: 'Child 1 Title'
});

App.Child2Controller = Ember.Controller.extend({
  title: 'Child 2 Title'
});

App.Child3Controller = Ember.Controller.extend({
  title: 'Child 3 Title'
});
```

How can I update the {{title}} property inside template="parent" when I'm inside a child controller? 
I've tried something like this

```
App.Child3Controller = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['parent'],
    init: function() {
    this.get('controllers.parent').set('title', 'Child 3 Title');
  }
});
```

But I does not update the parent template. So how do I accomplish this?

Comment: did my answer work out for you?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, editing my answer after your comment, the problem you are facing is that `init` from `Child3Controller` is not called the time you need it, so for this to work you should do it in your `parent.child3` route `setupController` hook:

```
App.ParentChild3Route = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    // the Ember.run.later is not necessary and is only to simulate a delay 
    // so you can actually see the title change, it would be actually
    // just fine to call this.controllerFor('parent').set('title', 'Child 3 Title');
    // directly when the setupController hook is invoked
    Ember.run.later(this, function() {
      this.controllerFor('parent').set('title', 'Child 3 Title');
    }, 1500);
  }
});
```

I'm also redirecting to the `parent.child3` route from the `index` route to make the `setupController` hook actually fire, but this could happen also by simply navigating to the `parent.child3` route in any other way:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  afterModel: function() {
    this.transitionTo('parent.child3');
  }
});
```

So to conclude, changing values in a controller should be done in the `setupController` hook of the controller corresponding route.

I've tried to simulate this in a simple [demo](http://jsbin.com/odosoy/72/edit), have a look.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Guys thanks for all the reply's!
You guys gave me a idea and it solved my question :)

Check it out here http://jsbin.com/AhOT/3/

As you can see I took another way to solve it ;)

Comment: One thing I'd add to this answer is that if you want to retain the behavior of your existing controller, be sure to call `this._super(controller, model)` at some point in the `setupController` method to resume control.

Answer (score 0):

Guys thanks for all the reply's! You guys gave me a idea and it solved my question :) Check it out here [jsbin.com/AhOT/3](http://jsbin.com/AhOT/3) As you can see I took another way to solve it ;)